# prove that $supp(π^{∗} f) = (supp f)×N.$ Please can you check my answer? Also more explanation please.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

My question is that 
Let $f \colon M \to R$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on a manifold $M$. 
If $N$ is another manifold and $π \colon M \times N \to M$ is the projection onto the first factor, prove that
$\operatorname{supp}(\pi^{*} f) = (\operatorname{supp} f)\times N$.

And my answer is here. Please can you check my answer? Do you have any mistake or drawback? Also pleas more explain about what I write.Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You want us to explain what you write? Also, this doesn't really have anything to do with geometry or real analysis (not directly, anyway). Anyway, it looks correct.

Comment: Yes, but If my answer is false, I want you to write more explanation. Ok? @tomasz sorry for wrong taggs.

Comment: Can @tomasz you see my mistakes? Please can you show these in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all seems correct. Can you expound why ${\rm cl}_{M\times N}(A\times N)={\rm cl}_M(A)\times N$?

Comment: Ohh thank you:) yes please can you explain this? Because I have seen this rule as a lemma in a book. So I have used. But I dont know how to show:( thank you @Berci

Comment: Since ${\rm cl}_M(A)\times N$ is closed and contains $A\times N$, we have the $\subseteq$ inclusion, and if $(m,n)\in{\rm cl}_M(A)\times N$, and we consider any of its open neighborhood, that contains a base set $U\times V$ around $(m,n)$, so $m\in U$ and thus $U\cap A\ne \emptyset$, therefore $(U\times V)\cap (A\times N)\ne\emptyset$, meaning $(m,n)\in{\rm cl}_{M\times N}(A\times N)$.